# Where can I get paid dogecoin for work?

Tags: dogecoin, services

Are there any services/freelancer websites where I can get paid in dogecoin?

Comment: That's quite unlikely, as Dogecoin is still "small". However you can get paid in Bitcoin which is very easy to convert to Doge: thttp://www.reddit.com/r/Jobs4Bitcoins/

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa: If you add a sentence or two that would be a valid answer. Could you perhaps post it as such?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa: I've expanded my suggestion on meta here: [Please post answers as answers, not as comments!](http://meta.bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/633/5406)

Comment: @Murch, Thanks. As it is not direct answer to the question, because the author is specifically asking for a Dogecoin paid work, I would not post the answer unless the author confirms this could be a working solution for him/her too :)

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa "I am not aware of any options to get paid in Doge, but you could instead..." seems to be a valid answer to me. There might be a better one,  but it might be the best.

Comment: Cool. Let's see if any other answers pop in, then I'll add mine.

Comment: http://www.reddit.com/r/dogemarket